# Open only .xls files in a given directory using macro

Tags: excel, xls, vba

Just wondering... I have a piece of code - a macro in excel that allows me to open files in a given directory. The thing is that I only want to open .xls files, and the code that I have opens all the files in a given directory.

Can anyone help me with this matter.

Thanks.

```
Sub FindOpenFiles()
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, folder As Scripting.folder, file As Scripting.file, wb As Workbook
Dim directory As String

    directory = "O:\test"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(directory)

    For Each file In folder.Files
        Workbooks.Open file
    Next file
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub FindOpenFiles()
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, folder As Scripting.folder, file As Scripting.file, wb As Workbook
Dim directory As String

    directory = "O:\test"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(directory)


    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") + 1) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open directory & Application.PathSeparator & file.Name
        End If
    Next file
End Sub
```

This woks fine...

Answer (score 1):

See if this works, may need a tweak or two!

```
For Each file In folder.Files
    If Right(file, 4) = ".xls" Then
        Workbooks.Open file
    End If
Next file
```

Comment: Brilliant, glad to see you got what you required! Does this code work as is?

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to upvote, if you think it is a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this but I am not really sure

directory = "*.xls"